# Spring QA profile and beans names

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have 4 beans, which are depend on a profile of my app, now I run my app with QA profile:

```
    @Bean
    @Profile("!qa")
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> eventConsumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(saslConsumerConfig(eventConsumerConfig()));
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("!qa")
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> primeEmployeeConsumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(saslConsumerConfig(primeEmployeeConsumerConfig()));
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("qa")
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> simpleEventConsumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(eventConsumerConfig());
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("qa")
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> simplePrimeEmployeeConsumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(primeEmployeeConsumerConfig());
    }
```

I have 2 other beans, they use these consumerFactories:

```
    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>>
    kafkaEventListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, String> eventConsumerFactory) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(eventConsumerFactory);
        factory.setAutoStartup(autoStartupFlag);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>>
    kafkaPrimeEmployeeListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, String> primeEmployeeConsumerFactory) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(primeEmployeeConsumerFactory);
        factory.setAutoStartup(autoStartupFlag);
        return factory;
    }
```

My code doesn't work, I got error `No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: simpleEventConsumerFactory,simplePrimeEmployeeConsumerFactory`

But when I try to name my QA beans:

```
    @Bean("eventConsumerFactory")
    @Profile("qa")
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> simpleEventConsumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(eventConsumerConfig());
    }

    @Bean("primeEmployeeConsumerFactory")
    @Profile("qa")
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> simplePrimeEmployeeConsumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(primeEmployeeConsumerConfig());
    }
```

I'll get an error that I don't have any bean of `ConsumerFactory<String, String>`.
Where have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you declare two beans with the type ConsumerFactory<String, String>, and sure you get the message:

No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>' since Spring try to bind jour bean by type.
But if you declare bean's id (for example  `@Bean("primeEmployeeConsumerFactory")`) Spring try to bind by id's, and you should use @Qualifier in your bean usage place.

For more information see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation)

Comment: It didn't help. I tried to use @Qualifier, but I still get the same problem

Comment: public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>>
    kafkaEventListenerContainerFactory(@Qualifier("eventConsumerFactory") ConsumerFactory<String, String> eventConsumerFactory) {}

No beans found...